# I can't uninstall and re-install Thunderbird

Tags: uninstall, email, thunderbird

My problem is that I can't uninstall and re-install Thunderbird. I'm running Ubuntu. Try as I may, via direct download or terminal commands, I can't upgrade and can't uninstall/reinstall. It’s Thunderbird 68.10. No errors via terminal. Via direct download, generally none. I am allowed to uninstall (after which Thunderbird disappears), but when I then download Thunderbird (whatever the newest version is), I get 68.10 again.

Any your thoughts on this issue, please? Thank you.

Comment: That is an incredibly old version of Thunderbird. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Assuming you are using a supported version of Ubuntu, please update your question and show the exact text of any errors and warnings you are receiving; don't paraphrase or summarize them for us.

Comment: It would also help us if you can post both the commands that you have tried, and the results or error messages that Ubuntu throws

Comment: Hello Charles,

Very sorry for the delay. I was traveling.

I tried both this: 

$ sudo apt-get install thunderbird

and this: 

sudo apt update sudo apt install thunderbird

The first did download files, but nothing changed operationally. The second did nothing. 

Much appreciated.